# HTTP-based metadata provider with SSL - Using MethodInvokingFactoryBean for Java-based configuration

Tags: spring-saml

I'm learning example on https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample and I don't understand why author using both MethodInvokingFactoryBean and TLSProtocolConfigurer in WebSecurityConfig. What difference between them? Essentially the same results was obtained in each separate case of creating beans and MethodInvokingFactoryBean result has been overridden by TLSProtocolConfigurer.

**com.vdenotaris.spring.boot.security.saml.web.config.WebSecurityConfig**

```
@Bean
public KeyManager keyManager() {
    DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
    Resource storeFile = loader
            .getResource("classpath:/saml/samlKeystore.jks");
    String storePass = "nalle123";
    Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<String, String>();
    passwords.put("apollo", "nalle123");
    String defaultKey = "apollo";
    return new JKSKeyManager(storeFile, storePass, passwords, defaultKey);
}

@Bean
public TLSProtocolConfigurer tlsProtocolConfigurer() {
    return new TLSProtocolConfigurer();
}

@Bean
public ProtocolSocketFactory socketFactory() {
    return new TLSProtocolSocketFactory(keyManager(), null, "default");
}

@Bean
public Protocol socketFactoryProtocol() {
    return new Protocol("https", socketFactory(), 443);
}

@Bean
public MethodInvokingFactoryBean socketFactoryInitialization() {
    MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetClass(Protocol.class);
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetMethod("registerProtocol");
    Object[] args = {"https", socketFactoryProtocol()};
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(args);
    return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
}
```

**org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer**

```
private String protocolName = "https";

private int protocolPort = 443;

private KeyManager keyManager;

private String sslHostnameVerification = "default";

private Set<String> trustedKeys;

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    ProtocolSocketFactory socketFactory = new TLSProtocolSocketFactory(keyManager, trustedKeys, sslHostnameVerification);
    Protocol p = new Protocol(protocolName, socketFactory, protocolPort);
    Protocol.registerProtocol(protocolName, p);
}

@Autowired
public void setKeyManager(KeyManager keyManager) {
    this.keyManager = keyManager;
}
```

Would you please tell me what I missed?